# Like counter javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I can not run my like counter in javascript. 
The replacement of the empty heart with the full one works properly but the counter update no. Can someone help me? Thank you

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM totlike WHERE id_user_like = $id_user AND id_post_like = ". $risultato['id'].""); 
                      if(mysql_num_rows($query2) ==1) {
        $like='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id="'. $risultato['id'] .'"></i>';
                      } else {
                    $like='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" id="'. $risultato['id'] .'"></i>';
                      }
echo '<div class="list" id="list_'. $risultato['id'] .'">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="btn-group pull-right postbtn">
        <button type="button" class="dotbtn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="dots"></span> </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="segnalazione('. $risultato['id'] .');">Segnala</a></li>
              '. $delete .'
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="question" id="question8025"><a href="profile.php?id='. $risultato['id_user'] .'" class="question-user"><div class="img imgLiquid imgLiquid_bgSize imgLiquid_ready" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 0px auto; background-image: url(&quot;download.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;"><img src="download.jpg" id="questionavatar" style="display: none;"></div></a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="profile.php?id='. $risultato['id_user'] .'" class="hashtag" rel="nofollow">'. $risultato['username'] .'</a><br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday, 2:00 am</small> </h4>
            <p><h4><a href="post.php?id='. $risultato['id'] .'" class="hashtag" rel="nofollow">'. $status = nl2br($risultato['post']) .'</a></h4></p>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left ">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" onclick="like(' . $risultato["id"] . ','. $risultato['total_like'] .' );" id="'. $risultato["id"] .'">'.$like.' '.$risultato['total_like'].'</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>';
```

and then

```
function like(id_post, tot_like) {

  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '../ajax/like.php',
       data:{id_post:id_post},
       complete: function() {
           var elem = $('#'+id_post).attr('class');
           if (elem=="glyphicon glyphicon-heart") {
               $('#'+id_post).removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-heart').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty');
               $('#'+id_post).text(tot_like - 1);
            } else {
               $('#'+id_post).removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-heart');
               $('#'+id_post).text(tot_like + 1);
            }
       }
  });
```

When I click the counter goes to -1 or +2

Answer (score 0):

You must have a refresh after you update by clicking on +1 or -1 which you are not doing it.
Also you must do ++ or -- which will be better. 
1º Get the total likes, 2º show them as you are doing till now, 3º update which the user action, 4º get again refreshing o just update DOM object with +1 or -1 but will be quite useless and there may occur some error soon or mistake.

Comment: Thanks, you can give me an example because I do not understand the javascript

Comment: I explained it quite a bit but well so resuming again by stages: 1º get the likes as you are doing, after you show them. 2º you have already the buttons ready for +1 or -1 and what you do is the total -- or total++ updating the database and not in the html element, so you update db and instantly refresh after getting reply from server-side..